# file still read-only after a mount --bind from a rw partition

Tags: centos, rhel, mount, readonly

I use `mount --bind` to "overlay" a file from one `ext4,rw` filesystem onto another file in `ext4,ro` filesystem. For example, `/etc/hosts` is on a read-only `/` partition, but I have another partition where `/rw/etc/hosts` is writable. So when I do

```
# mount --bind /rw/etc/hosts /etc/hosts
```

any writes to `/etc/hosts` will go to `/rw/etc/hosts`

---

This worked fine in `CentOS 6.3`.

```
# mount -o ro /dev/sdc1 /ro
# mount -o rw /dev/sdc2 /rw
# mount --bind rw/test ro/test
# echo 1 > rw/test
# cat ro/test
1
# echo 2 > ro/test                    # [1]
# cat rw/test
2
```

But I cannot get it to work in `CentOS 6.4` I repeat the steps from above, but I get an error when trying to write to `ro/test`:

```
# echo 2 > ro/test                    # [1]
-bash: ro/test: Read-only file system
```

`SELinux` is disabled. Any ideas what could cause this to stop working?

CentOS 6.3 kernel: `2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64`
CentOS 6.4 kernel: `2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64` and `2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64`

Comment: CentOS 6.3 and CentOS 6.4 have had a variety of different kernel versions. Can you be more specific about the versions of the kernels that do and do not work for you?

Comment: @KenStailey Updated the question with the kernel versions.

Comment: Probably a bug of some kind, but what happens if you specifically *`mount -o remount,rw`* your test?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas what could cause this to stop working?

Probably a bug that was introduced into the kernel along with support for fsfreeze.  I opened [BZ #951311](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=951311) to track this.

Comment: I don't have access to the bug you filed, but I will file one myself. It could be related/duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

```
# mount --bind rw/test ro/test
# echo 1 > rw/test
```

You can only mount directories.

You cannot use echo to write into a directory.

You probably want

```
# mount --bind rw ro
```

Comment: You can `mount --bind` files. Please see:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44373/single-bind-mounted-file-gets-out-of-sync-in-linux

Comment: Heh, the man page for `mount(8)` needs some updating.  The man page for `mount(2)` gets it right but `mount(8)` says `newdir` and `olddir` not `newnode`, etc.