# Using inotifywait along with vim

Tags: files, vim, rsync, inotify

I have simple script that monitors file for changes and rsyncs it with remote copy:

```
#!/bin/bash

while inotifywait -e close_write somefile
do
    rsync somefile user@host.domain:./somefile
done
```

It works just fine with nano, but fails with vim. When i use nano, it outputs :

```
somefile CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
```

and starts next loop waiting for another edition.

When i use vim, there is no output, script just closes with exit code 0.

I did some research and found out that close_write is right parameter for uing initofywait along with vim (first i wanted to use modify event), yet for some reason it fails for me.

Comment: It works for me. You did _change_ the file in vim before saving it, rather than just opening it for editing?

Comment: @roaima It only works if the `backupcopy` option is off.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312794/inotify-dont-treat-vim-editting-as-a-modification-event

Answer (score 22):

Editors can follow several strategies to save a file. The two major variants are to overwrite the existing file, or to write to a new file and move it in place. Writing to a new file and moving it in place has the nice property that at any point in time, reading from the file gives you a complete version of the file (one instant the old one, the next instant the new one). If the file is overwritten in place, there's a time during which it is incomplete, which is problematic if some other program accesses it just then or if the system crashes.

Nano apparently overwrites the existing file. Your script detects the point when it's finished writing (the `close_write` event) and runs `rsync` at that point. Note that it is possible for rsync to grab an incomplete version of the file, if you save twice in quick succession, before rsync has completed its job from the first save.

Vim, on the other hand, uses the write-then-move strategy — something to the effect of

```
echo 'new content' >somefile.new
mv -f somefile.new somefile
```

What happens to the old version of the file is that it gets deleted at the point where the new version is moved into place. At this point, the `inotifywait` command returns, because the file it's been told to watch no longer exists. (The new `somefile` is a different file with the same name.) If Vim had been configured to make a backup file, what would happen is something like

```
echo 'new content' >somefile.new
ln somefile somefile.old
mv -f somefile.new somefile
```

and `inotifywait` would now be watching the backup.

For more information on file save strategies, see [How is it possible to do a live update while a program is running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138214/how-is-it-possible-to-do-a-live-update-while-a-program-is-running/138241#138241) and [File permissions and saving](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/file-permissions-and-saving/89091#89091)

Vim can be told to use the overwrite strategy: turn off the [`backupcopy`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backupcopy%27) option (`:set nobackupcopy`). This is risky, as indicated above.

To handle both save strategies, watch the directory and filter both `close_write` and `moved_to` events for `somefile`.

```
inotifywait -m -e close_write,moved_to --format %e/%f . |
while IFS=/ read -r events file; do
  if [ "$file" = "somefile" ]; then
    …
  fi
done
```

Comment: The drawback to the method proposed here is that when you write several files "at once", your commands will be run once for each file. I'm editing code, so I may modify a header and a couple other translation units and `:wa`. Then my build is run once for every file written.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement That's a much more complicates use case than the one in this question. For your use case, you'd need to wait a bit after one file is saved. Files are never really modified “at once”. If you save multiple files with `:wa`, you get successive inotify events. You'd need to wait after the first one to see if others are coming. But you can use the code presented here: the additional complexity would go inside the `…`.

Comment: @Gilles I decided on `while true; do inotifywait ... [no -m]; make; sleep .1; done;` or so. There are some gotchas, but I've arrived at something quite workable.

Comment: I think Vim changed these options' names so this answer is worth updating

Comment: @DoronBehar Did it? I link to the manual and it doesn't suggest that anything has changed. If something has changed, please edit my answer to say what to do depending on the version (keep in mind that not everyone uses the latest version).

Comment: You are right :) I got confused between that and the option `backup`.

Comment: Seems the option needs to be set with this actually `:set backupcopy=yes`