# How do I prevent sed -i from destroying symlinks?

Tags: sed, symlink

Why does `sed -i` executed on symlink destroys that link and replaces it with destination file? How to avoid this?

eg.

```
$ ls -l pet*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madneon madneon 4 mar 23 16:46 pet
lrwxrwxrwx 1 madneon madneon 6 mar 23 16:48 pet_link -> pet

$ sed -i 's/cat/dog/' pet_link

$ ls -l pet*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madneon madneon 4 mar 23 16:48 pet
-rw-rw-r-- 1 madneon madneon 4 mar 23 16:49 pet_link
```

And why isn't it considered a bug?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `-i`/`--in-place` flag edits a file in place. By default, `sed` reads the given file, processes it outputting into a temporary file, then copies the temporary file over the original, without checking whether the original was a symlink.

GNU `sed` has a `--follow-symlinks` flag, which makes it behave as you want:

```
$ echo "cat" > pet
$ ln --symbolic pet pet_link
$ sed --in-place --follow-symlinks 's/cat/dog/' pet_link
$ cat pet
dog
```

Comment: It doesn't edit a file in place, but edits a temp copy of the file in the current directory then moves that temp copy over the original.

Comment: @mikeserv I skipped the implementation details because the question was about the interface. Good to know though, thanks!

Comment: GNU sed has `--follow-symlinks`; BSD sed does not. If you're on macOS or another BSD variant, you'll need to install GNU sed via your package manager (brew, pkg, etc).

Comment: `then copies the temporary file over the original` – It actually *moves* the file, replaces the old one *atomically*. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37177/108618) to get the point. In general copying is not atomic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, this is by design since `sed` is a **S**tream **ED**itor, not a file editor. It basically makes a copy and replaces the original file with the copy. <sup>[BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)</sup>

Alternatively you can use `ex` command instead which has similar syntax for substitution, e.g.

```
ex +%s/cat/dog/ge -scwq pet_link
```

or multiple files:

```
ex "+bufdo! %s/cat/dog/ge" -scxa **/pet_link*
```

It won't destroy the symbolic links.

Related: [How do I prevent sed from destroying hardinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/305661/21471)

Answer (score 1):

I find that this also works well (preserving both symbolic and hard links):

```
sed 's/cat/dog/' pet_link > pet_link.tmp
cat pet_link.tmp > pet_link
rm pet_link.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that we sometimes use to write to the same file as is read from. Here is an excerpt from the man page:

```
   sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
   Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening
   the output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and
   write to the same file.

   It also creates the output file atomically by renaming a temp file into
   place, and preserves the permissions of the output file if it already
   exists. If the output file is a special file or symlink, the data will
   be written to it.
```

Here is a snippet that shows that it can preserve symbolic links, although I usually use it to preserve inodes:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

rm -f pet pet_link
echo "cat" > pet
pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head -v pet

pl " Results, before sed:"
ln --symbolic pet pet_link
ls -ligG pet pet_link
# sed --in-place --follow-symlinks 's/cat/dog/' pet_link
pe
pe " Results, after sed:"
sed 's/cat/dog/' pet_link | sponge pet_link
head -v pet
ls -ligG pet pet_link
```

which produces:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
==> pet <==
cat

-----
 Results, before sed:
1571283 -rw-r--r-- 1 4 Nov 26 23:03 pet
1571286 lrwxrwxrwx 1 3 Nov 26 23:03 pet_link -> pet

 Results, after sed:
==> pet <==
cat
1571283 -rw-r--r-- 1 4 Nov 26 23:03 pet
1571286 lrwxrwxrwx 1 3 Nov 26 23:03 pet_link -> pet
```

On a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
```

The sponge code is available in a package *moreutils* -- some details:

```
sponge  soak up standard input and write to a file (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/sponge
Package : moreutils
Home    : http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/
Version : 0.52
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
```

At our shop, we wrote a version that writes to a temporary file for the case of very large files.

The package is available on Debian, Fedora, macOS (via brew), etc. ... cheers,