# How do I prevent sed from destroying hardlinks?

Tags: sed, hard-link

My question is similar to [How do I prevent sed -i from destroying symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192012/how-to-avoid-sed-i-to-destroy-symlink), but concerning hardlinks.

Using `sed -i` to work on a file destroys all the hardlinks the file has, since sed works by writing to a temporary file and then moving this.
The `--follow-symlinks` parameter doesn't help in case of a hard link.

Is there an alternative to using the rather ugly:

```
sed 's/cat/dog/' pet_link > pet_link
```

Comment: That alternative isn't just ugly, it doesn't work, because it truncates the file before reading from it.

Comment: Why doesn't sed just check the file's link count, and if it's more than 1, copy all the data instead of moving the directory entry?

Answer (score 12):

For `sed 's/cat/dog/'` or any other substitution that doesn't change the size of the file, with any Bourne-like shell, you can  do:

```
sed 's/cat/dog/' < file 1<> file
```

The little-known but over 35 year old¹ [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_07) `<>` operator is to open a file in read+write mode *without truncation*. Basically, here that makes `sed` write its output over its input. It's important to make sure that the output doesn't overwrite sections of the file that `sed` has not read yet.

For substitutions that cause the file size to decrease, with `ksh93`:

```
sed 's/hippopotamus/ant/' < file 1<>; file
```

`<>;`, a `ksh93` extension is the same as `<>` except that if the command being redirected succeeds, the file gets truncated where the command finished.

Or with perl:

```
perl -pe 's/hippopotamus/ant/;
          END{truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT}' < file 1<> file
```

For anything else, just use the standard form:

```
cp -i file file.back &&
  sed 's/dog/horse/g' < file.back > file # && rm -f file.back
```

---

¹ Though the initial implementation in the Bourne shell and early versions of the Korn shell was actually broken, fixed in the late 80s. And the Almquist shell initially didn't support it.

Comment: Can you add link to refer old¹?

Comment: @cuonglm, see for instance https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/#sunos5 the code was in the first version of the Bourne shell in 1979, but broken there. Was fixed in ksh88 ([still broken in ksh86](https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/tree/master/local/toolchest/ksh)) and in several Bourne shell variants, `<>` was [added to NetBSD in 1999](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/bin/sh/redir.c#rev1.20), to FreeBSD in 2000. pdksh had it from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `sed` is a **S**tream **ED**itor, not a **file** editor, therefore people tend to abuse it for trying to edit files. Basically `-i` option is non-standard FreeBSD extensions (may not be available on other operating systems), secondly it doesn't edit files - it makes a copy and replaces the original file with the copy. <sup>[BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)</sup>

The alternative is to use [`ed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)) or `ex` command (part of Vim) which has similar syntax, e.g.

```
ex +%s/cat/dog/e -scwq pet_link
```

Or as per [@Wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305661/how-to-avoid-sed-to-destroy-hardinks/341603#comment604199_341603) recommendation:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/cat/dog/' x | ex pet_link
```

---

For multiple files, you can use:

```
ex "+bufdo! %s/foo/bar/ge" -scxa **/*.lnk
```

If your shell supports [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (enable by: `shopt -s globstar`), using `**` in this case will work recursively.

---

For more [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) syntax, you can try (as per [@Wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305661/how-to-avoid-sed-to-destroy-hardinks/341603#comment604207_341603) suggestion):

```
for f in *.txt; do printf '%s\n' '%s/cat/dog/g' x | ex "$f"; done
```

or:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s\n" "%s/cat/dog/g" x | ex "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

---

Related:

- [BashFAQ/021](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)
- [Simplest way to properly search and replace source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8611822/55075)

Comment: The first command given (1) only runs the substitution on the first line of the file, and (2) fails to *exit* if the pattern isn't found on the first line, instead dropping silently into interactive mode (but with no prompts).  Instead I'd recommend `printf '%s\n' '%s/cat/dog/' x | ex pet_link`, which runs the substitution on *all* lines, but exits without changing the file if the pattern is not present.

Comment: And for multiple files, to do it POSIXly, either `for f in *.txt; do printf '%s\n' '%s/cat/dog/g' x | ex "$f"; done` or to do it recursively within subdirectories, `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s\n" "%s/cat/dog/g" x | ex "$f"; done' sh {} +`.  Feel free to put these into your answer if you like.  And +1 just for using `ex`.

Comment: `-i` was added first to GNU `sed` (2001-09-25) based on the same `-i` option in `perl` and shortly after ([2002-05-07](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=96175)) and independently  but with a different syntax on FreeBSD. And much much later NetBSD ([2014](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/sed/main.c?rev=1.22&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN)) and OpenBSD ([2015](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/sed/main.c?rev=1.19&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)) added one with the GNU style.

Comment: `**/` is not so _new_, [it was added to `zsh` in 1992](/a/62665)

Comment: While `vim` has another implementation of `ex`, `ex` was initially written in the mid 70s and included in 1BSD. `ed` predates even Unix.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of `ed`:

```
$ ed pet_link <<END_OF_ED
g/cat/s//dog/
w
END_OF_ED
```

This doesn't break the hard link.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this works well (preserving both symbolic and hard links):

```
sed 's/cat/dog/' pet_link > pet_link.tmp
cat pet_link.tmp > pet_link
rm pet_link.tmp
```