# Why does sed -i replace symlinks with a file?

Tags: linux, sed

I noticed a strange behaviour when applying an edit using `sed -i` on a symlink. The documentation sais `-i` will do an in-place edit. However, the symlink is replaced with a file.

Steps to reproduce:

```
cd /tmp
echo blah > foo
ln -s foo bar
sed -i -e 's/ah/ub/' bar
ls -l
```

will result in:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 arogge   arogge      5 Mar  9 15:07 bar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 arogge   arogge      5 Mar  9 15:07 foo
```

Is this intended behaviour or is it a bug in `sed`?

Comment: adding the additional parameter `-c` makes sed do what I thought it should do anyways

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

The `-i`/`--in-place` flag edits a temp copy of a file and then moves that copy over the original.

So when you do:

```
sed -i 'bla' symlink
```

What sed is doing is:

```
sed 'bla' symlink > temp_file
mv temp_file symlink
```

And hence destroying the symlink by placing a regular file in its place.

Info taken from [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192012/how-do-i-prevent-sed-i-from-destroying-symlinks#comment323313_192017) in [How do I prevent sed -i from destroying symlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192012/40596)

Answer (score 0):

Does the full listing include something like this

`lrw-rw-r--. 1 arogge   arogge    5 Mar 9 15:07 bar-e -> foo`

It is the intended behaviour. From the man page for sed

> -i extension
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.

It appears that sed is interpreting the -e as the extension to -i.

Comment: no, that's not what happens.