# Sed: what is the difference between -i and > file?

Tags: sed, files

I know that `> file` is not `sed` specific, and that it writes `stdout` to the file, but how does this compare to `sed`'s `-i` option? I read the man page, and I do not understand what `in-place` means. Are either of these choices definitively better? Which is faster? Takes less ram? If you have any additional insights, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In-place" means the operation uses space (like diskspace or memory) already taken, no additional resource is needed. In this context it's about sticking to the provided `file`.

The main advantage of `sed -i -e '…' file` is you can read `file` and have the output in a file still named `file`. It looks like the same file, but behind the scenes [it's not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192017/108618). By default, `sed` reads the given file, processes it outputting into a temporary file, then moves the temporary file to the original name, replacing the original file.

So it's not *strictly* "in-place" because another file is needed and at some point you have *two* files; but the result is almost as if it was in-place. Writing to a separate file [has its benefits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37177/108618):

> The old version of the file is atomically replaced by the new version, so at every point in time the file name points to a valid, complete version of the file.

On the other hand `sed -e '…' file >file` doesn't work. Worse, it makes `file` lose its content. The behavior is explained here: [Bending a pipeline back into its origin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558773/108618). If you try to achieve with `>` what `-i` does then you will most likely lose data.

Comment: "If you try to achieve with `>` what `-i` does then you will most likely lose data." This is important to note (I learned it the hard way).

Answer (score 2):

It all depends what you want to do - but pipes are generally very fast and just uses IO buffers.

**-i** is a non-standard option to edit files **in place**. sed otherwise just transforms the data on standard in to standard out

On my machine I can't notice any speed difference on a 1mb file.

```
$ cat my_file.txt 
This is my file
$ sed -i "" s/my/your/g my_file.txt
$ cat my_file.txt 
This is your file
$
```