# VI editor changes and does not change inodes of files when editing files under /tmp

Tags: centos, vi, inode

I noticed that my vi editor changes inodes when editing files, except when that file is under /tmp. Why is this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you see, and what you expect to see?

Comment: Yes, when I edit I file in VI, the inode changes for every time I save the file, but when I am editing a file under the /tmp directory, the inode does not change when editing a file under "/tmp"

Comment: the vim options may be in /etc/vimrc

Comment: Thanks guys, I had noticed "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36467/why-inode-value-changes-when-we-edit-in-vi-editor", but that did not answer why inodes would remain constant when files were edited under "/tmp". I think this lays in /etc/vimrc, like jeff-schaller mentioned.