# Vi editor message - input encoding conversion not supported

Tags: vi

I'm currently using FreeBSD10, when i open a file using vi then a message displays at the end of file- "Input encoding conversion not supported". 
Is this to warning or error ?
Note:- However the file can still be modified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why inode value changes when we edit in "vi" editor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36467/why-inode-value-changes-when-we-edit-in-vi-editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a warning.  For instance, vi may notice a character combination which hints that the file is (for example) really using UTF-8 because it includes characters in the upper control range C1 (128-159).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm seeing this warning for all the files (even empty file). I see both - vi option fileencoding and inputencoding is set to US-ASCII. The file is a simple ASCII text file, still it displays the warning.